# How to have values from 3 columns shown in combobox VBA (active x control)

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

In combobox I set columnCount to 3, so when I click dropdown arrow I can see 3 columns that I need, but when I choose one row that I need, there is only value from first column shown. Combobox is wide enough for all three columns. Is there a way to see all 3 when I select my choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the ListFillRange to all the columns in your list:
**Sheet1!$A$5:C20**

Also you need to have a single cell referenced in the LinkedCell property: **Sheet1!$A$1**

The bound column must be a value between 1 and 3.  You can only return a single value from the list - this will be from the bound column.

Your column count must be 3.

Your column widths must be either blank or a value >0 (0 will hide the column):
**85.05 pt;85.05 pt;85.05 pt**

With those in place you should be seeing three columns of values in the list box - you can only return a value from one of those columns though.
If you want to return more than one I'd suggest using a hidden (column width of 0) column to contain a unique identifier and then use a look-up on the sheet to fill in the blank columns.

To get to all three columns in VBA use code similar to:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    With Me.ComboBox1
        MsgBox .Column(0) & vbCr & .Column(1) & vbCr & .Column(2)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have ListFillRange set to 3 colums, I don't have LinkedCell, because i don't need it. I read value directly from combobox. Basicly you're telling me that I can't have values of 3 column even if I can see them when I selecting them in dropdown manu?

Comment: @Jelovac - If you want to get to the select columns using VBA you can use:
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    With Me.ComboBox1
        MsgBox .Column(0) & vbCr & .Column(1) & vbCr & .Column(2)
    End With

End Sub

Comment: I could use this option instead of lookUp. Thank you! I noticed Me.ComboBox1! What is this Me. used for? It works without it aswell, but I've seen it often in some code exemples. ???

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  
The Me keyword when placed within a form module refers to the form itself, if placed within a sheet module it refers to the sheet and if placed within  the Workbook module it refers to the workbook.

Feel free to vote up, mark as answer or whatever it is to get my rep up so I can comment on other peoples posts. :)

Comment: I would vote up, but i have to have >=15 reputation to be able to vote. But you can vote up for my question to suport me to be able to vote for you some day?! I can only check as "accept answer", and I did that.